# c++ win 32, I want to add list of items into a combo box. how do i do it

Tags: c++, winapi

I want the user to select from a drop-down list of items in a combo box. 
I have called the WM_CREATE function and the user can input text.
Here, I've been able to add 'Item 2', 'Item 1' seems not to show. What should I do?
This is what I have

```
#define WC_COMBOBOX

case WM_CREATE: {

//  CREATE COMBO BOX

HWND hWndComboBox = CreateWindow (TEXT("COMBOBOX"), TEXT (""),
            CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
            100, 20, 200, 20,
            hwnd,(HMENU) NULL, NULL, NULL);

//  ADD 2 ITEMS
SendMessage (
    hWndComboBox,
    (UINT) CB_ADDSTRING ,
    (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) TEXT ("Item 1"));
SendMessage (
    hWndComboBox,
    (UINT) CB_ADDSTRING,
    (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) TEXT ("Item 2"));


//  SEND THE CB_SETCURSEL MESSAGE TO DISPLAY AN INITIAL ITEM IN SELECTION FIELD
SendMessage (hWndComboBox, CB_SETCURSEL, (WPARAM) 1, (LPARAM) 0);
```

(Fixed formatting)

Comment: Step one would be creating a combo box, not an edit control.

Comment: i have done that please, what next

Comment: @LinDavidCollins I think our edits got mixed up. Please edit again.

Comment: please I ve changed the 'EDIT' to 'COMBO BOX'. What next please?

Comment: Have a look at the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775794(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Potter. It would really help. I will study it then apply to see if it works. Thank you once again.

Comment: It should say `#define WC_COMBOBOX L"COMBOBOX"` (assuming unicode). Just remove that line. Add `#include <commctrl.h>` instead.

Comment: You should increase the height of your combobox which is currently set to 20. Try 200 instead. Propably "Item 1" is within the list but not shown...

Comment: It is good to put value (control ID) for `HMENU` member. Unique number e.g. `101`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code.

```
//  CREATE COMBO BOX
    HWND hWndComboBox = CreateWindow (
        WC_COMBOBOX,
        TEXT(""),
        CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
        10, 20, 70, 17,
        hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

//  ADD 2 ITEMS
    SendMessage (
        hWndComboBox,
        (UINT) CB_ADDSTRING,
        (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) TEXT ("Item 1"));
    SendMessage (
        hWndComboBox,
        (UINT) CB_ADDSTRING,
        (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) TEXT ("Item 2"));

//  SEND THE CB_SETCURSEL MESSAGE TO DISPLAY AN INITIAL ITEM IN SELECTION FIELD
    SendMessage (hWndComboBox, CB_SETCURSEL, (WPARAM) 1, (LPARAM) 0);
```

Comment: i tried it but am told expected primary expression before ',' token. Previously I had 'WC_COMBOBOX is not declared so I defined it. Please what primary expression should I add? Thanks though @ ninja

Comment: Add `#include "commctrl.h"` which defines `WC_COMBOBOX`

Comment: Please the same error code after adding 'expected primary expression before ',' token' @ Mr. Barmak

Comment: What compiler are you using? You can also edit your question again, Copy/Paste the exact code.

Comment: You're not supposed to redefine `WC_COMBOBOX`; Windows provides that for you.